# limits and the floor function

Tags: limits

I want to use the result that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n - 1} \rfloor}{n} = 0.$$ However, I don't really know how to work with the floor function. Can I re-write $\frac{\lfloor \sqrt{n - 1} \rfloor}{n}$ in some way to get something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ that definitely goes to $0$?

Comment: What do you find confusing about the floor function?

Comment: Squeeze using $\sqrt{n-1} -1 < \lfloor \sqrt{n-1}\rfloor \le \sqrt{n-1}$

Comment: @peterwhy so there is no closed expression ?

Comment: what do you mean by closed expression ? you can follow by $\sqrt{n-1}<\sqrt{n}$ and get the $\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}$ you want.

Comment: @zwim I thought maybe there was some kind of expression like $\frac{1}{\lfloor n \rfloor}$ for this division but that doesn't seem to be the case. the squeeze trick does work pretty easily as peter said, totally forgot about that. Cheers everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the floor function always rounds down, and since the square root is an increasing function, we have that

$$\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\rfloor\leq\sqrt{n-1}\leq\sqrt{n}.$$

We then have that

$$0\leq\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\rfloor}{n}\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Now as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, the result follows from the Squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for any integer $n$, the floor function just returns that integer, so we can just ignore the floor function.

Now let's rationalise it to get the following: $$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{n-1}{n\sqrt{n-1}}\right)$$
We will then divide it by the highest denominator power to get the following: $$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)$$

We can then take the limit to infinity to get $0/\infty $, which is obviously $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, what's greater than $\sqrt{n - 1}$ and contains nothing subtracted to $n$ within the root?

Comment: Why down voting my answer??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is pretty confusing. I'm not at all sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Okay, I thought about it some more, and I now know what you're suggesting, but it is hard to understand.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC That's what you consider. You find an upper bound that converges to zero. In this case you can use    $\sqrt{n - 1}<\sqrt{n}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ is the term I was asking for. It's more helpful to suggest a thought instead to just commit the answer.